# How to check if there are recently viewed products

Tags: magento2, recently-viewed

I need to do a check if there is any recently viewed product and if so, then need to display some text.

Does anyone know, how to check if there are recently viewed products?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `getCount()` method in block here `\Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed` and used in `module-reports/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/viewd.phtml`

Comment: it return how many products are viewed But not return each product how many time viewed as shown on Dashboard when we click on Most Viewed Product Tab.